# Wrong Sound Blaster's PCI ID within Windows

Tags: windows, hardware-failure, creative

I own Sound Blaster X-Fi Titanium, it was working with no problems under Linux or Windows 7. It's original PCI ID is [`1102:000b`](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/1102/000b) but now I see different within MS Windows.

- BIOS setup: `1102:000b`
- GNU/Linux: `1102:000b`
- Windows 7: `1102:000d`
- Windows 8: `1102:000d`

In last days I'm experimenting with IOMMU PCI passthrough in Xen and I tried to pass this device to virtual Windows 7 and 8. Here I found this problem. I don't know if this is just coincidence or reason of my problem but now it's wrong even in physical system.

Windows detects `1102:000d` as a High Definition Audio sound device (I guess this name, I have localized Windows, but this is general name, the same was with Realtek HDA before drivers), it's playing but it's unstable (Windows speaker testing can crash that application) and I can't install Creative software. Used driver is `hdaudio.sys`.

Booting in BIOS or UEFI mode doesn't change anything. Nor CMOS clean. Someone met the [same problem](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/full-3d-gaming-in-virtual-machine.740227/page-2#post-6973405).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using original CD (even outdated) with drivers. These can be installed unlike those on the web. After installation device is shown as `1102:000b` which is correct. But I can't still understand this `000d` problem.